# Use a program on a Raspberry Pi without an OS

Tags: operating-systems, software-development

I'm a software developer and all the programs that I have developed were to run on an operating system. Now, I'm going to start developing software for Raspberry Pi and I'm wondering if I can create a program that runs on Raspberry Pi without operating system.

Is that possible?

I'm thinking to create a program and save it on a ROM or something like that, I'm sell it installed on Raspberry Pi (or maybe on a custom board).

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is technically possible; it's called *bare metal programming*. If you choose to go this route, you should know that it's not particularly simple. You'll need to do it in either C or ARM assembly (probably at least a little inline ARM).

That being said, this is a huge undertaking, and I highly doubt it'd be worth it for you. Think of every system call your application makes. You'll need to write those from scratch, and somehow incorporate basic drivers for things like HDMI, the SD reader, etc into your program.

The RPi is not a simple device, and I do not recommend this course of action for anything other than a learning experience.